# What type of SSL does a FTP sub domain, WWW or NON-WWW require?

Tags: https

We have a few web servers and an FTP server that sits behind our public IP that is used for a few applications. We need to get an SSL Certificate that I can install on each of the servers to pass PCI requirements.

Currently, I have been using self-signed certs but that’s not good enough for the standard so I have to buy a publicly trusted one. All of the servers are reached through the same FQDN that points at the IP address.

*These are the domains and their sub domains:*

- `ftp.example.com`
- non-www `example.com`
- with-www `www.example.com`

Will a basic cert work? I guess I’m confused as to whether the ftp.domain counts as a subdomain or not. All the other servers are separated buy for and forwarding at the firewall level.

Comment: So are you use FTPS, or FTP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple SSL certs cover the main domain (`example.com`) and one fixed sub-domain (`www.example.com`), if you want to use a custom sub-domain such as `ftp.example.com` then you will need to purchase a CERT that supports additional subdomains.

Comment: Or one having as SAN a wildcard: `*.example.com`.